# ubuntu applications segfaults and filesystem remounts with readonly mode

Tags: filesystem, read-only, segmentation-fault

i dropped a hard disk. after installing fresh kubuntu 12.04LTS applications keeps segfaulting and filesystem remounts with readonly mode. i checked hard disk for bad sectors but none are found.

/var/log/messages is empty and /var/log/dmesg contains nothing error like.

is there a way to use this hard disk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The remounting happens because this line in `/etc/fstab`:

```
/dev/sda1 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
```

Which tells the system to remount the partition in read-only mode where / resides when a read/write error is detected. (So your data won't get damaged / more damaged.)

Thus I feel that it is likely that your disk got indeed damaged. Though I'm not sure why `fsck` isn't detecting it as it is supposed to do so.

As a temporary solution you can try to reformat the whole drive (as that will mark bad sectors on the disk as unusable and preventing any operations on them), but that is only a temporary solution and on the long run you'll have to get a new disk.
(And frankly living with faulty hardware is quite annoying.)

The segfault is probably because a block got corrupted on the disk which your program either tries to use or execute.